# How to render list in parallel in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example if I have some list of IDs in `ItemList` component:

`{itemIds.map((itemId, index) => {   return <Item key={itemId} itemId={itemId} />; })}`

and then inside `Item` component I make API request for each of the items by their ID.

How do I make these ID requests to run in parallel in the best possible way? Do I really have to use `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()`? Any alternatives to that?

Comment: If the individual requests are made in `<Item />` and you render a bunch of `<Item />`s at the same time, then the requests will also be made at the same time. So why do you think that they don't run in parallel?

Comment: @Thomas Silly, but I didn't test that. I will come home and revisit/try that. Can you please explain the logic behind this, like why would that actually run in parallel? I have a thought that this is due to iterative operation on each individual cell in the array with `callbackFn` that is not related to the rest of the cells in the array, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you need all you data to resolved together you need to use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`, if you want to show whatever item resolved you can send the request from each item.

But from the backend perspective, whatever method you use to call the data this way will lead to a lot of requests to the server, especially if there are a lot of items.

It would be better to make an API to send the IDS and return all these items together in one request and from the front end, you loop through the items.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this is unrelated

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use async/await in a for loop, like this example :

```
async function getItems(itemIds) {
  const items = [];
  for (const itemId of itemIds) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/items/${itemId}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    items.push(data);
  }
  return items;
}

getItems(itemIds)
  .then(items => {
    // Handle the array of item data
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle any errors
  });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will make it sequential, due to the nature of the `await`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are right, await is sequential. I think that if you want to run the requests in parallel, using Promise.all() or Promise.allSettled() is the best option